# Create a PDF document for printing in Qt from a template

Tags: c++, qt, pdf

I write an application, when a user inserts data in a dialog window (document title, sender name and address, etc) and then my application should generate a PDF file from this user data.

The PDF file should have a defined layout, something like this:

[image]

I tried to do this with `QPdfWriter`, but I had problems aligning text in the PDF. Here's my code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QPrinter>
#include <QPdfWriter>
#include <QPainter>

QString currDate()
{
    QDate date = QDate::currentDate();
    return date.toString("dd.MM.yyyy");
}

void pdf(QString filename)
{
    QPdfWriter writer(filename);
    writer.setPageSize(QPagedPaintDevice::A4);
    writer.setPageMargins(QMargins(30, 30, 30, 30));

    QPainter painter(&writer);
    painter.setPen(Qt::black);
    painter.setFont(QFont("Times", 10));

    QRect r = painter.viewport();

    QString citydate = "City, ";
    citydate += currDate();

    painter.drawText(r, Qt::AlignRight, citydate);


QString sender = "COMPANY XYZ\n";
sender += "Random Street 12/314A\n";
sender += "123-1232 City\n";

painter.drawText(r, Qt::AlignLeft, sender);
    painter.end();
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    pdf("example1.pdf");

    return a.exec();
}
```

The date printed to the PDF is on the left, but:

1. I have trouble with further text — how to "move" painter to
   different locations, to print also the sender name, document title,
   and document content inside the page (is the `translate` method of the painter enough, or can it be done simpler?)
2. I don't know how to handle page breaks, in case the document content will be very long (will spread on 2 or more pages)

I also tried the `QTextDocument` approach, but it's hard to write any document, with almost no example available on the web. I came up only with this:

```
void pdf(QString filename)
{
    QPrinter printer(QPrinter::PrinterResolution);
    printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
    printer.setPaperSize(QPrinter::A4);
    printer.setOutputFileName(filename);
    printer.setPageMargins(QMarginsF(30, 30, 30, 30));

    QFont headerFont("Times New Roman", 8);
    QFont titleFont("Times New Roman", 14, QFont::Bold);

    QTextCharFormat txtformat = QTextCharFormat();


    QTextDocument doc;
    doc.setPageSize(printer.pageRect().size());

    QTextCursor* cursor = new QTextCursor(&doc);

    txtformat.setFont(headerFont);
    cursor->insertText("Company XYZ", txtformat);

    cursor->movePosition(QTextCursor::Right && QTextCursor::EndOfLine, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor, 1000);
    cursor->insertText(currDate(), txtformat);

    doc.print(&printer);
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are several ways to create a PDF document in Qt. You already mentioned two of them. I propose some improvement for the `QTextDocument` approach. Rather than manually writing a `QTextDocument`, you can create it from HTML-formatted text.

```
QString html =
"<div align=right>"
   "City, 11/11/2015"
"</div>"
"<div align=left>"
   "Sender Name<br>"
   "street 34/56A<br>"
   "121-43 city"
"</div>"
"<h1 align=center>DOCUMENT TITLE</h1>"
"<p align=justify>"
   "document content document content document content document content document content document content document content document content document content document content "
   "document content document content document content document content document content document content document content document content document content document content "
"</p>"
"<div align=right>sincerly</div>";

QTextDocument document;
document.setHtml(html);

QPrinter printer(QPrinter::PrinterResolution);
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
printer.setPaperSize(QPrinter::A4);
printer.setOutputFileName("/tmp/test.pdf");
printer.setPageMargins(QMarginsF(15, 15, 15, 15));

document.print(&printer);
```

Warning: `QTextDocument` supports a [limited subset](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html) of HTML 4 markup.

Comment: Thank you. Three things: 1) how to get rid of page numbers? 3) can I move page numbers, for instance, on the left or center it? 3) I see that your approach handles page breaks automatically (goes to the new page when the old page ends), however, do you know how to achieve the same using `QTextCursor` (my second approach)?

Comment: @Brian Brown 1) If the document is not paginated, the current page number is printed at the bottom of each page. Document is paginated if the page size specified. So, to get rid of page numbers, you need to set the page size: `document.setPageSize(printer.pageRect().size());`. 2) Position of a page number hardcoded, you can't change it. 3) `QTextDocument` handle page breaks automaticaly, no matter how document was created.