# Qt print document to PDF

Tags: qt, pdf

I cannot print a QTextDocument to pdf. What I basically want is to print a table of data as a cell into a pdf file. The program runs on a virtual windows server. So I tried this:

```
Q_INVOKABLE QString ScriptCallback::htmlToPdf(const QString& sHtml) {
qDebug() << "Html To Pdf";
QPdfWriter pdfWriter("c:\\test.pdf");
pdfWriter.setPageSize(QPagedPaintDevice::A4);
pdfWriter.setPageMargins(QMargins(30, 30, 30, 30));
QTextDocument document;
document.setHtml(sHtml);
document.print(&pdfWriter);
QString s = "";
return s;
```

}

In fact instead of printing to the testfile I want to print to a QBuffer -> QByteArray. But this one above is for testing.
The problem is, I always get the error

> QPainter::begin() failed

In Debug Mode the program continues, but in release the program even crashes trying to run the command

> document.print(&pdfWriter);

I don't care about using QTextdocument or QPdfWriter. The only thing I am interessted in, is taking a bunch of data and somehow generate a table in a pdf file.
By the way the program runs as a console app (QCoreApplication). But I included gui and printsupport modules. So any alternatives are welcome as well.

Comment: Update: I tried using QApplication instead of QCoreApplication but the issue remains the same...

Comment: Also I tried this solution, that still caused the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33654060/create-pdf-document-for-printing-in-qt-from-template